# Weird Bash I/O redirect behavior

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm noticing weird behavior in Bash regarding redirection and can't explain it. When I type

```
ls <>a
```

the current directory's files print to stdout (Bash shell), the file `a` is created and is left empty. I would expect an error because no input file was ever specified.
When I type

```
ls >< a
```

I get an error (unexpected token '<'). Seems to me that, if the first thing happens, this should attempt to use file `a` as input to ls. This feels inconsistent.
Doing

```
ls <>
```

gives me an error (unexpected token 'newline')

```
 ls ><
```

gives me a different error (unexpected token '<')

Can anybody explain what's happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<>` is a valid bash operator, not consecutive `<` and `>` operators.  `><` isn't a valid operator, so it *does* get interpreted as consecutive `>` and `<` operators.  Check the [man page](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/documentation/bash/bash.html):

> The redirection operator
>
> ```
> [n]<>word
> ```
>
> causes the file whose name is the
>   expansion of `word` to be opened for both reading and writing on file
>   descriptor `n`, or on file descriptor `0` if `n` is not specified. If the
>   file does not exist, it is created.

Comment: Because it was opened on file descriptor 0 (standard input).  You didn't redirect the output.  I quoted the man page in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

>< isn't a valid Bash builtin. <> is, however.

```
[fd] <> *word*
```

All it does is cause the file whose name is an expansion of the input to be opened for both reading AND writing on that file descriptor.

If you want to know more about it, and other redirections, http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections is a good source.

Oh, when you hit "enter", you create a newline in the terminal, which is what the shell thinks is the word.